# Unresolved externals on simple mapnik c++ application

Tags: mapnik, c++, visual-studio

I'm attempting to write a simple win32 x64 console application in c++ using VS 2017 that uses the Mapnik v3.0.9 SDK to render a png from a pgsql database.

All I've done so far is include a reference to the mapnik/map.hpp header file and attempting to build produces the following unresolved externals:

> unresolved external symbol "private: static enum mapnik::logger::severity_type mapnik::logger::severity_level_" (?severity_level_@logger@mapnik@@0W4severity_type@12@A)
>
> unresolved external symbol "private: static char const * * mapnik::enumeration::our_strings_" (?our_strings_@?$enumeration@W4well_known_srs_enum@mapnik@@$01@mapnik@@0PEAPEBDEA)
>
> unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > mapnik::enumeration::our_name_" (?our_name_@?$enumeration@W4well_known_srs_enum@mapnik@@$01@mapnik@@0V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A)
>
> unresolved external symbol "private: static char const * * mapnik::enumeration::our_strings_" (?our_strings_@?$enumeration@W4aspect_fix_mode@Map@mapnik@@$08@mapnik@@0PEAPEBDEA)

I've included the mapnik.lib and all boost lib files for the linker, I'm not sure how to proceed here. Any ideas on what I could be missing?

```
#include <mapnik/map.hpp>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what does the code look like?

Comment: Added the code, nothing much really

Comment: It looks like you're missing additional mapnik includes — have you checked any docs?

Comment: There arent many docs for c++, I'm getting most of what I have from the examples. I did have a lot more includes previously, but those just generated more unresolved externals, so I took them out to focus on just getting this one working.

Comment: Add mapnik/symbolizer_enumerations.hpp and maybe mapnik/enumeration.hpp

Comment: Getting about 40 unresolved externals of the type: `private: static char const * * mapnik::enumeration<enum mapnik::well_known_srs_enum,2>`. The `well_known_srs_enum,2` is whats usually different across the various errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74700/discussion-between-lynxlynxlynx-and-user1435899).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the prebuilt SDK at the moment does not support VC++ 2017.

After downloading and installing 2015, the exact same project builds fine.